# What is the difference between cv2.imread and open().read?

Tags: numpy, opencv, mxnet

I have this code:

```
import cv2
im = cv2.imread("0.jpg")
print(len(im.tobytes()))
fp = open("0.jpg", 'rb')
imb = fp.read()
print(len(imb))
```

They are different! Now a function take 'imb' format as input. But I just have 'im'. I must use the cv2.imwrite to the disk and then use fp.read()?
Is there a faster way?

I use the mxnet image imdecode. imdecode take 'imb' as input. But im is what I get. How to pass the 'im' to the mx.img.imdecode?

https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/issues/13545

Comment: Yes, there is a faster way converting an image to `png` compressed data in memory using [`cv2.imencode`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html#imencode)

Comment: `cv2.imread()` understands the JPEG header and DCT coefficients, quantisation, entropy coding and reads in the image and organises it into a rectangular grid of BGR pixels for you. `fp.read()` just gives you all the bytes in the file with no concept that it is an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with mxnet framework. But according to the code you gave, I guess you want image data in binary format.

Take a look at OpenCV [cv.imencode()](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.4/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga461f9ac09887e47797a54567df3b8b63) API.

```
import cv2
im = cv2.imread("0.jpg")
img_encode = cv2.imencode('.jpg', im)[1]
```

I think the variable *`img_encode`* is might what you want.

Or try to use `cv2.imwrite` in more intuitive way like Memory Filesystem in "pyfilesystem" module.[[link]](https://docs.pyfilesystem.org/en/latest/reference/memoryfs.html)